# What is the value of p in 'Foo *p = new Foo()' if Foo's constructor throws?

Tags: c++, exception

I'm not sure how to phrase this question so that google can help me.

A colleague asked me this earlier today (in other words):

Given the following code:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() {throw 1;}
}

Foo* bar()
{
    Foo *p = NULL;
    try
    {
        p = new Foo();
    }
    catch (...) {}

    return p;
}
```

According to the C++ standard, is bar() guaranteed to return NULL, or is the behavior implementation-defined? I'm guessing it's the latter, from articles I've read about the double-checked locking idiom being broken in C++.

Answer (score 4):

If the constructor throws, the assignment does not happen, so `p` has whatever value it had before.

So yes, `bar` is guaranteed to return `NULL` in your code snippet.

And this has nothing to do with double-checked locking; that's an unrelated concurrency issue.

Comment: But the compiler is allowed to reorder assignments in some circumstances (which is what I was referring to in my mention of double-checked locking), so I'm looking for wording from the standard that prohibits it from assigning p to point to the memory allocated for the new object before running the constructor code.

Comment: The assignment cannot possibly happen before the value of `new Foo()` is determined.

Comment: Fred is correct but, if you're _really_ paranoid, you could always set `p` back to `NULL` in the `catch` clause :-)

Comment: consider the following 'pseudo-code' for the code generated by the compiler: `p = malloc(sizeof(Foo));try{new (p) Foo();} catch (...) {free(p); throw;}`. Is the compiler prohibited from implementing the line `p = new Foo();` in that way?

Comment: @Bwmat Ah, now I see what you're getting at. Let me ponder that for a while :)

Comment: @Bwmat: The compiler is allowed to reorder assignments (or do anything else its authors see fit) as long as it does not change the observable behavior of the program. This reordering would change the observable behavior of the program.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley more precisely, as observed from the thread that is executing. Other threads may observe unusual behavior. (It is this unusual behavior as observed by other threads that leads to the double check locking problem.)